# Solving ODE in Python, output does not match my own calculations

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I'm trying to solve a simple ODE with one variable: **x_dot = sqrt(x)*sin(x) + x** with the *scipy.integrator.solve_ivp* function, but dont really understand the answers. Here is my code:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sqrt = np.sqrt
sin = np.sin

def dx_dt1(t,x):
    return (sqrt(x)*sin(x)) + x

#### Solve ODE

t = np.round(np.linspace(0, 10, 1001),2) #Want timestep of 0.01
y0 = np.linspace(0.1, 1, 10) #List of initial values

sol = solve_ivp(dx_dt1,[0,10],y0,t_eval=t)

data = sol.y
```

From `data` I get lists of all the initial values and their next steps. I would expect the solution *x_{i+1} - x_{i} = x_dot*, but when I calculate *x_dot* myself and multiply it with 0.01, it is different. Have I done something wrong with my timestep or is it something I have misunderstood?

Comment: How did you "calculate `x_dot` yourself", did you call the `dx_dx1` function, did you use a pocket calculator? If the last, did you care to put it in "radians" mode (which is the most likely source for radically different results)?

Comment: Also, `t_eval` has no effect on the time step -only the output time points, where the solution is actually interpolated, not "computed"). You should use `max_step` to specify the maximum allowed time step. I also recommend looking in the documentation for the arguments `atol`and `rtol`, as they enable you to control the precision of the solution.